Using formvalidation.io in a Bootstrap 5 modal
I am loading a remote page into a Bootstrap 5 Modal using AJAX
Code to open the modal:
<button type="button" data-id="5" class="btn btn-status">Open</button>
 
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" id="support_modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Support Ticket</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.btn-status').click(function () {
          var custId = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
               url: 'driver_support.php',
               type: 'get',
               data: { custId: custId },
               success: function (response) {
                  $('.modal-body').html(response);
                  $('#support_modal').modal('show');
               }
          });
       });
   });
</script>

This works as expected however...
The page I am loading in the modal (driver_support.php) is using formvalidation.io for validating a form.
When the page is viewed directly in a browser, the validation works correctly
When the page is loaded into the modal via AJAX it doesn't validate the form.
There are no errors in the console.
Code in the page loaded into the modal (driver_support.php):
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Support Ticket</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="formvalidation/dist/css/formValidation.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="formvalidation/dist/js/FormValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="formvalidation/dist/js/plugins/Bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="tickets" id="tickets" action="my_script.php" method="post">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label text-dark">Post a reply</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Reply</button>
</form>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) { 
    FormValidation.formValidation(document.getElementById('tickets'), {
        fields: {        
            message: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter a message'
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        plugins: {
            trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
            submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
            defaultSubmit: new FormValidation.plugins.DefaultSubmit(),
            bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap5({
                rowSelector: '.mb-3',
            }),
        },
    });
});
</script>

Thanks for your time.

The problem is when you load the page with AJAX, the validation script is executed under the document load listener:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
//...

and as it shares the same document, the DOM is already loaded, so it never executes.
As the scripts in loaded page load synchronously, you could simply remove the listener, and let the code run right after JQ adds it to the modal:
// remove the listener
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) { 
    FormValidation.formValidation(document.getElementById('tickets'), {

Also, to avoid conflict, you could consider using iframe, see: set innerHTML of an iframe
